# Why does no small Rj45 port exist?

Tags: ethernet

While I bought my last Tablet I noticed that no Tablet (and most smaller notebooks /convertibles) has a Rj45 port. Which I finde quite dissatisfying since I like to use RJ45 in numerous places.
I think a reason could be that Rj45 is simply too big for a Tablet - it is downright massive compared to micro USB /HDMI etc.
But that leads me to my question: Why is there no attempt to build a smaller micro-Rj45 port which could be used in constrained spaces?

Comment: RJ45 is actually a large version of RJ11 (or RJ12). Just get a micro USB RJ45 adaptor. Micro USB on 1 end - Full size RJ45 Ethernet adapter on the other.  Then it's a matter of drivers.  I use mine on a laptop not a tablet.

Comment: Some tablets can be fixed to detachable keyboards, often, these keyboards contain additional IO ports. As to why it hasn't been developed yet, this is very opinion based I think. How do you expect us to answer that?

Comment: Basically, the average tablet user has no idea what an RJ45 port is (no matter how you might name it) or how one might use it.  How many homes are wired for Ethernet, vs simply using WiFi?

Comment: Great question, I wondered this too already. :)

Comment: When there is a market, such a product will emerge. I would not buy it. I bought a small mobile device to be, well, mobile, not tethered to a hole in the wall.

Comment: Prior to the wide availability of wifi a number of manufacturers created small ethernet connectors that then attached to dongles for the full size RJ45 connector.  These were most commonly used in PCMCIA and cardbus cards, where space was at a premium. The connectors were not as durable and inexpensive as the typical RJ-45, though, and once wifi became ubiquitous, there was little reason to continue to go down that path. You are an exception. 99% of users don't need, want, or would ever use ethernet from their mobile device, so it make no sense to pursue that.

Comment: Hmm... As an embedded systems engineer, I disagree with the flagging of this question as opinion-based. There are several quite concrete reasons for this and several of them are listed in the answers already present. Granted, this question could probably receive a more thorough answer from electrical engineers on electronics.SE.

Comment: i asked this on the [electronics SE for TabletPCs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/332080/like-mini-and-then-micro-usb-why-is-there-is-no-micro-rj-45-8p8c-for-native-eth)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's actually a few elements to this. Firstly invariably, ethernet is an additional, add-on chip,  rather than something that's part of an SOC. Without a compelling reason for it manufacturers probably prefer to save a few dollars by leaving it out when not needed. In theory you *could* use an alternate port design, I seem to recall a zenbook model with a hinged full sized ethernet port, HDMI could do ethernet in theory, and there's a [zenbook model that seems to use its displayport as a ethernet adaptor](http://www.trustedreviews.com/asus-zenbook-ux302_Laptop_review)(For some reason asus experiments a lot with this sort of thing)

Practically in most situations where you're using a small, ultraportable device, you probably would be using wifi rather than ethernet. If you absolutely *must* have it, there's always the old stand-by of using a usb ethernet adaptor.

Its really an economic thing, more than anything else. There's not much demand for a non poweruser for ethernet in devices too small or slim for a full sized port, and a non standard port would not be likely to catch on

Comment: incidentally, I used a Lenovo IdeaPad the other day which has a hinged fullsize ethernet socket that allows it to fit in with the curved edge of the underside. Interesting feature however I don't anticipate lasting very long mechanically if constantly moving between multiple ethernet sites

Comment: That may have been what i was thinking of

Comment: Well, but the reason no SoC includes ethernet is that there is no demand. And dthere is no demand because (among other things) RJ45 is so big, no sane person would add it to a mobile phone or tablet! There are ethernet IP cores available to add to your own SoC

Comment: @Josef Typically the ethernet controller may be included in the SoC, but the ethernet PHY isn't, as it uses a slightly different process optimized for the particular electrical characteristics of the PHY.  It isn't because the connector is too large - many of these mobie chips are used in a wide variety of industrial and other devices that use ethernet.  It's a reasonable tradeoff between cost and utility to support the widest variety of platforms possible.

Comment: There's a conflation here of what protocol data is being encoded with and the cable for the protocol.  These aren't (always) the same thing.  Both HDMI and DisplayPort support multiplexing multiple data types on a single cable. Technically there is no reason why you couldn't plug an ethernet cable into your receiver and then share that network connection with your TV, video game system, or anything else connected via HDMI.  In reality, this confuses most consumers because they expect one cable to do one thing.  Your zenbook just utilized more of the spec than most manufacturers.

Comment: Several TabletPCs still retain the ethernet nic electronics as evidenced in device manager and lspci, but there is simply no port for it.  The first generation of the following is a good example.  The second gen includes mini-rj45.      https://www3.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-x/Thinkpad-X1-Yoga-2nd-Generation/p/22TP2TXX12Y?IPromoID=LEN760377

Comment: Only noobs use wi-fi when they could be using 10G ethernet

Answer (score 7):

I think there is a difference between Tablets and other types of computers like Desktops, Laptops and Servers.

Tablet's main aim to acquire mobility. So, Wifi or 3G is the most suitable connectivity method for tablet devices. Tablet manufacturers may not interested in giving a solution for your problem because that is not average tablet user's demand.

Comment: Agreed. It is about economics and average users. Which sadly means that you may want to carry a tablet and *need* to carry additional devices (either unelegant USB based NICs or an extra laptop).

Comment: In case of pure Tablets I agree. But even expensive Convertibles have no Rj45, which is not so great.

Answer (score 4):

The above answers from Journeyman and U-map are correct that a general lack of demand combined with the size of the connector and, to a lesser extent, the cost of the Ethernet PHY chip are among the primary reasons for leaving these off of most tablets and thin laptops. However, especially where tablets and other devices with small batteries are concerned, power is also an issue. From my experiments on development kits, I've found that shutting down the Gigabit Ethernet PHY saves about a Watt. While that's not a big deal for most laptops, it's a much bigger deal with tablets (and especially phones.) Also, the fact that USB-attached Ethernet NICs are cheap and readily available for the relatively small subset of users that actually want to use wired Ethernet on their mobile devices makes the manufacturers be even less worried about leaving it off.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Astounding that the ethernet eats so much energy.

Comment: Yeah, getting a bunch of 125 MHz signals down 100 meters of wire without bit loss requires more power than you might think, especially when each of those pairs can have 5 possible voltage states rather than just 2 like most digital busses.

Comment: When it comes to TabletPCs nowadays, the ethernet nic is still in the hardware, but there is no port to connect up.  Makes it much more difficult to pxe boot even iPXE boot when the OS you are booting does not have the driver for usb to ethernet.

Comment: @rjt Fortunately, I've never needed to PXE boot my tablet.

Comment: @ reirab, try managing a fleet of TabletPCs.  The nature of their portability offsite is by itself a reason that mobile computers should be wiped and reinstalled fresh more often than desktops.

Answer (score 2):

Smaller ethernet ports actually do exist.  The [XJack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XJACK) was a connector used on PCMCIA modems and network cards that folded up and retracted inside of the card when not in use.  Instead of using a housing that completely surrounded the RJ45 connector, the cable connected at an angle and the jack had just enough material to make an electrical connection and hold the cable in place.  It looked odd and was awkward to use at first, but it worked, and it didn't take up much space.

Type II PC cards are only 5mm thick, so the XJack would have been no thicker than that.  That's plenty thin, even for today's thin devices.  I think the reason that tablets/phones lack ethernet ports is not a matter of the connector.  As other people have mentioned, it's the internal circuitry that device makers want to avoid.  The extra cost (and probably more important, power consumption) associated with adding ethernet isn't worth the benefit.  Using wired ethernet with a tablet is also contrary to their being marketed as "mobile devices", since you end up tethered to the wall.

Comment: While I agree about the power, as an embedded systems designer myself, I'd almost say that the connector size is even more of an issue, especially for phones and tablets which tend to be, not only very thin, but also generally lack much unused space inside the chassis at all. Even for the connectors that collapse and fold up, that's still a lot of space that they take up internally in the context of a tablet or, especially, a smartphone. Even on somewhat larger embedded devices, space is still a very big design consideration.

Comment: We have Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Yoga TabletPCs that Win10 and Win8 indicate have internal ethernet circuitry, but there is no port.  Trying to step a remote user on how to PXE boot is easy when there is an RJ-45 port.  Even if only used for initial install and initial user logon and sometimes password changes every 42 days.